# windows phone filedeployer question

Tags: windows-phone-7

soryr this is still related to my previous thread but i created this new thread to attract some answers.. anyway.. I'm using the [WP7 emulator](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation) however keep getting the "access is denied" error while using FileDeployer object to transfer files between device to my desktop.. I have emailed the author (Justin) but no reply..

Can anyone please suggest? I really need this urgently for my project.. thanks

Comment: It appears that the situation has changed with the Mango SDK, which can still be used to create 7.0 applications. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that feature is no longer supported in the RTM version of the tools.

You might want to look into [Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/). I'm not sure if it officially supports automation, but it uses HTTP so there's definitely a hook.

**Edit:** As of the "Mango" SDK, you can use the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to take and restore snapshots of an application's isolated storage to/from a local directory:

```
# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe ts xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"

# Copy data from IS to directory
ISETool.exe rs xd <PRODUCT-ID> "C:\TempDirectory\IsolatedStore"
```

Comment: using isolated storage explorer is not an option for the project. There are a lot of automations and customisation so I need a direct control to WP7..

Comment: @user384080 Then I'm afraid you're out of luck

Comment: Richard.. perfect.. just in time the release of beta 2.. just what i needed.. thanks!